# How do i get objects by ForeignKey in Django 3.2

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I am building menu items for `Irvine` class and want to categorize them by `Category`

models.py

```
class Irvine(models.Model):
    objects = None
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Irvine Item')
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    size = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Category')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Irvine'
        verbose_name = 'Irvine Item'
        ordering = ['-published']


class Category(models.Model):
    objects = None
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_index=True, verbose_name="Category")
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = '* Categories'
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        ordering = ['name']
```

view.py

```
def irvine(request):
    irvine = Irvine.objects.all()
    context = {'irvine': irvine}
    return render(request, 'cafe/irvine.html', context)

def by_category(request, category_id):
    santaanna = SantaAnna.objects.filter(category=category_id)
    costamesa = CostaMesa.objects.filter(category=category_id)
    irvine = Irvine.objects.filter(category=category_id)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    current_category = Category.objects.get(pk=category_id)
    context = {'santaanna': santaanna, 'categories': categories, 'costamesa': costamesa, 'irvine': irvine, 'current_category': current_category}

    return render(request, 'cafe/by_category.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('add/', ItemsCreateView.as_view(), name='add'),
    path('<int:category_id>/', by_category, name='by_category'),
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('irvine', irvine),
```

with

```
  {% for i in irvine %}
    {}
    <tr class="danger">

      <th scope="row" width="20%">{{ i.name }}</th>
      <td width="60%">{{ i.description }}</td>
      <td width="10%">{{ i.size }}</td>
      <td width="10%">{{ i.price }}</td>

    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

I can grab all items from class Irvine, but how do i get items from this class by category

Comment: irvine has the object for category(ForeignKey), try printing irvine  in by_category method and share the result

Comment: I am new to Django and python, so i dont get what exactly should i print, will be tankful if you can specify.

Comment: @Mythilydevaraj ok, i get it, in html when i use i.category it shows the right category
```
  {% for i in irvine %}
    {% if i.category == Appetizers %}
```

Comment: Ok
'''
  {% for i in irvine %}
    {% if i.category == 'Appetizers' %}
'''
Doesnt work, however if i do  {% if i.name == 'potatoes' %} existing item, it shows me that item. Why cant i see i.categories?

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly check using `i.category` because it has list of values.

Try using `i.category.name`.

If you have serializer, please update the full code.

`{% for i in irvine %} {% if i.category.name == 'Appetizers' %}`, it will work